# Change default permission of MySQL database location

Tags: mysql

When create a database for ex: *test1* in MySQL , a folder named '*test1*' will be created in data folder of MySQL */var/lib/mysql* with permission **700**

```
mysql -uroot -p -e 'create database test1'
ll /var/lib/mysql|grep test1    
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 May 24 16:57 test1/
```

I want to change this default permission to **755**? (I mean if I run *mysql -uroot -p -e 'create database test1'* the folder 'test1' will have permission **755**). How can I archive this?

I have tried to change the UMASK and UMASK_DIR of current user then start the MySQL in safe mode but the permission still **700**

```
UMASK=0660
export UMASK
UMASK_DIR=0755
export UMASK_DIR
sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe &

mysql -uroot -p -e 'create database test2'
ll /var/lib/mysql|grep test2
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 May 24 16:57 test2/
```

Any help will be appreciated!
I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, MySQL 5.5.31

Comment: Why don't you just make a shell script that will create a database and then change the perms using `chmod`?

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to do this at all?

Comment: it does beg that question doesnt it

Comment: I want to change to 755 so that it can be copied (backup) by another shell script running by another account(not mysql) and this script is called by selenium test automatically. That's why I can not run it manually with 'sudo chmod' which terminate the process to ask for password

Comment: `sudo` can be set up to not require password for a certain user and program, i.e., `user ALL=PASSWD:ALL,NOPASSWD:/your/script` (this is on Fedora; other distros may have slightly different syntax).

Comment: @VedranŠego: tks so much for your quick reply. But I am not allowed to modify the sudoers(Ubuntu) due to the security risk!

Comment: This is far less of a security risk than opening your database for everyone to read. Mind you, with permissions, you'd also need to change perms on files (i.e., tables).

Comment: You can make a root cron-job to dump your database (`mysql_dump`) and set its ownership and permissions for the desired user. Messing with perms of a live database is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the problem is I'm not trying to find some workarounds but just wonder if we can set the default permission of the database location or not. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this work?

```
sudo UMASK=0660 UMASK_DIR=0755 /usr/bin/mysqld_safe &
```

Or edit /etc/initi.d/mysql.server and add -

```
UMASK=0660
export UMASK
UMASK_DIR=0755
export UMASK_DIR
```

This works for me.

You're also supposed to be able to specify `set-variable` in my.cnf but I couldn't get that to work.